# Tax on Stocks or ETF's

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

This is a really stupid question, but just to confirm: tax (credit) is accessed only on the realized capital gain (loss) from selling of stocks or ETF's, correct?

To answer the question from the commentator and answerer. This question concerns the US tax law.

Comment: You might wish to add a tag for your country, as we have members from all over the world.

Comment: This is assuming a standard brokerage account and not an IRA or 401k account, right?

Comment: @JBKing: Yes, you are right. Is the answer positive in this case?

Comment: @Hans no, not always.

Answer (score 3):

If you sell a stock, with no distributions, then your gain is taxable under [§1001](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1001).  But not all realized gains will be recognized as taxable.  And some gains which are arguably not realized, will be recognized as taxable.

The stock is usually a capital asset for investors, who will generate capital gains under [§1(h)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1#h), but dealers, traders, and hedgers will get different treatment.  If you are an investor, and you held the stock for a year or more, then you can get the beneficial capital gain rates (e.g. 20% instead of 39.6%).  If the asset was held short-term, less than a year, then your tax will generally be calculated at the higher ordinary income rates.  There is also the problem of the net investment tax under [§1411](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1411).  I am eliding many exceptions, qualifications, and permutations of these rules.

If you receive a [§316](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/316) dividend from a stock, then that is [§61](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/61) income.  Qualified dividends are ordinary income but will generally be taxed at capital gains rates under [§1(h)(11)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1#h_11).  Distributions in [redemption](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/302) of your stock are usually treated as sales of stock.  [Non-dividend distributions](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/301#c) (that are not redemptions) will reduce your basis in the stock to zero (no tax due) and past zero will be treated as gain from a sale.

If you exchange stock in a tax-free reorganization (i.e. contribute your company stock in exchange for an acquirer's stock), you have what would normally be considered a realized gain on the exchange, but the differential will not be recognized, if done correctly.

If you hold your shares and never sell them, but you engage in other dealings (short sales, options, collars, wash sales, etc.) that impact those shares, then you can sometimes be deemed to have recognized gain on shares that were never sold or exchanged.

A more fundamental principle of income tax design is that not all realized gains will be recognized.  [IRC §1001(c)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1001#c) says that all realized gains are recognized, except as otherwise provided; that "otherwise" is substantial and far-ranging.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. This depends on the situation and the taxing jurisdiction. Different countries have different laws, and some countries have different laws for different situations.

For example, in the US, some investments will be taxed as you described, others will be taxed as "[mark to market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark-to-market_accounting)", i.e.: based on the FMV difference between the end of the year and the beginning of the year, and without you actually making any transactions. Depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive dividends on an investment, those are taxed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is:  You are not taxed on the original basis (purchase cost) of your investment.  If you pay $30 a share, and sell at $35, the $5 per share gain is taxable at time of sale.  But the $30 basis cost doesn't enter into tax calculations at all.  (So it's important to keep good records on your investments and how much you paid for them at purchase.)